# Verify Nonce returns false - Request Nonce returns correct value

Tags: plugin-development, validation, nonce

I'm trying to verify that the nonce I created exists but for some reason it keeps returning false, why is this happening?

Creating my nonce:

```
<?php wp_nonce_field('test_slider_action','test_slider_options_nonce'); ?>
```

Verifying my nonce exists:

```
if($_POST && wp_verify_nonce($_REQUEST['test_slider_options_nonce']))
    echo "TEST";
```

if I dump my `$_REQUEST` I get the correct value, but if I dump my wp_verify_nonce it returns false. If it matters, both my `$_POST` check and form / nonce creation is on the same page. What else do I need to get it to verify?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass the action to check your nonce against, [wp_verify_nonce](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_verify_nonce) has two parameters.

```
if($_POST && wp_verify_nonce($_REQUEST['test_slider_options_nonce'],'test_slider_action'))
    echo "TEST";
```